# Deleting rows in pandas data frame: Delete previous k rows each time a certain condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a pandas data frame, DF, shown below. All elements in DF are either positive integers or 0.

If column 'c' contains a value equal to k in the ith row, such that k is greater than or equal to 2, I would like to delete row i, row (i-1), ..., and row (i-(k-1)) (so k rows in total are deleted). I *only* require rows get deleted when column 'c' has a value of at least 2.

In the example, this happens once, where the 'k' in question is equal to 3, and is found in the 5th row (so I delete rows 5, 4, and 3 -- three rows in total, inclusive of the row that contained the value of '3').

Note if the jth row of column 'c' equals k, the previous k-1 rows will definitely equal 0, which means if row j is deleted, all other rows that were deleted would have only contained zeros in column c.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to do this?

For the image of the example data frame with the required result, please refer to https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHN8M.png:

[image]

The data frame:

```
A = matrix([[9, 9, 0, 9, 9],
    [1, 2, 1, 9, 9],
    [8, 8, 0, 2, 3],
    [7, 7, 0, 7, 8],
    [1, 2, 0, 3, 4],
    [6, 6, 3, 6, 6],
    [1, 2, 0, 1, 2]])
DF = pd.DataFrame(A)
DF.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this docs page](https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_dropping_column_and_rows.html) you can drop a range of rows by `df.drop(df.index[[2,3]])`. So if, as in your example, you find that row 5 triggers the drop, you can do this with:

```
df.drop(df.index[list(range(i-3, i))])
```

where `i` is 5. I haven't tested this, but you might be able to drop the cast to `list`.

Comment: Thanks. This worked (just had to add 1 to both arguments of the range function).